# Can't make the bootstrap collapsed nav fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I need two navs in my website: one fixed, other show-hide on click. When I click to show de first nav, it can't be above the second nav and I did it. But when scroll and I click to show the first nav, I can't get it fixed, and is not working the position:fixed.

I'm using bootstrap collapse (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

I just need that the first nav be fixed when scroll.

Obs: sorry if my english is not perfect =P

https://jsfiddle.net/8o8hr8qb/1/

```
.panel {
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
background: #000;
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 0;
top: 0}

.teste-menu {
width: 100%; 
background: #ccc; 
position: fixed; 
z-index: 99; 
top: auto;}

.collapse.menu-visivel {
display: block; 
visibility: visible;}

.btn-info {
float: right;
right: 45px;
border-radius: 0;
background: #000;
border-color: #000;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;}


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">This nav need to be fixed</div>
  </div>

  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">▲</button>
  </a>
</div>


<div class="panel panel-default teste-menu">
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse menu-visivel">
    <div class="panel-body">Fixed nav menu</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fixed nav menu must be inside the same container to expand its height

```
<div id="container" class="panel panel-default">

  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">This nav need to be fixed</div>
  </div>

  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">▲</button>
  </a>

  <div class="panel panel-default teste-menu">

    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse menu-visivel">
      <div class="panel-body">Fixed nav menu</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to fix the container

```
#container{position: fixed; top:0;height: auto;}
```

[I've updated your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/8o8hr8qb/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript catch event scroll to set first nav fixe, but i think it good solve.
You should set second inside first nav like :

```
    <div class="panel panel-default teste-menu">

  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">This nav need to be fixed</div>
  </div>

  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">▲</button>
  </a>
<div class="panel panel-default ">

  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse menu-visivel">
    <div class="panel-body">Fixed nav menu</div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is clear understanding. As much as I can understand, you want something like this. 
Try clicking the **button** as well scroll the page.
Let me know in comments, what exactly should happen or share a screenshot or design if you can't explain it in code.

---

Here i have created a div with class `fixed'and added`position:fixed` to it. so that the menu is always available.

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.panel {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #000!important;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
  top: 0
}
.teste-menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc!important;
  z-index: 99;
  top: auto;
}
.collapse.menu-visivel {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
.btn-info {
  float: right;
  right: 45px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #000;
  border-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="fixed">
  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">This nav need to be fixed</div>
    </div>

    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">▲</button>
    </a>

  </div>


  <div class="panel panel-default teste-menu">

    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse menu-visivel">
      <div class="panel-body">Fixed nav menu</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>



Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker. Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido
pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60,
quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker. Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica
e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração
eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus
PageMaker. Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos
de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e
mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker. Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor
desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na
década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker. Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria
tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto
para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica
como Aldus PageMaker. Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro
de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem
Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker. Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando
um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se
popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @TalitaKorb did it work ? If yes then you shoud mark the appropriate answer and close it.